# How to get Anaconda and Sublime to run python with the same interpreter

Tags: sublime-text, anaconda, jupyter

After installing both anaconda and sublime, I notice that I can import libraries using a jupyter notebook but am not able to import anything when running a script on sublime. How do I go about getting sublime to run using the same interpreter as anaconda/jupyter?